# How to retrieve data between 2 dates in android sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Hello Friends I want to retrieve data between 2 dates.I am using sql between clause it works fine when both dates are 2 digit or single.
**For Example:**

`SELECT * FROM EXPENSE WHERE EXP_DATE BETWEEN '20-12-2012' AND '21-12-2012'`

this query works fine but if i use date as `'9-12-2012' AND '20-12-2012'` it does not work..`returns null`

Comment: Store the dates in a better format - e.g. ISO8601 - which is well-sortable and *not* in a locale-specific format. 3 different strategies are talked about on the SQLite [datatype page](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)! SQLite does *not* have a "Date Time" type so there is *no* automatic conversion.

Comment: Change your date format and the problem would be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Query . It works for Me.

```
db.query(EXPENSE_TABLE_NAME, new String[]{"*"},
                        "(EXP_DATE  >= ? and EXP_DATE <= ? )" , new String[] {startDate,endDate}, " strftime(" + "\"%d" + "-" + "%m" + "-" + "%Y\""  + ",EXP_DATE) ",null ,null);
```

Comment: `strftime` generates zero-padded fields; this is not the format used in that database.